# lambda node.js Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, aws-lambda, null

here a code that i has write it in lambda to get data form url and insert parameter into dynamoDB

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'ap-southeast-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters));
    const requestId = context.awsRequestId;
    await createMessage(requestId).then(() => {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: `
            <hl>query string parameters</hl>
            <p>${JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters)}</p>
            <p>one: ${obj.one}</p>
            <hr/>
            <hl>path</hl>
            <p>${JSON.stringify(event.requestContext.http.path)}</p>
            <hr/>
           `,
            headers: {
                 'Content-Type' :  'text/html; charset=uft-8',
            }
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
    })
};

function createMessage(requestId) {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'Message',
        Item: {
            'messageId' : '321',
        }
    }
    return ddb.put(params).promise();
}
```

here it's Response

```js
{
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
  "trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:5:20)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

[this is a request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CVPs.png)

what should i do next to fix unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: I guess `event.querystringParameters` is undefined. Second, change the line ` var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters));` to ` var obj = event.queryStringParameters` since parsing and stringifying the same object is comparable by adding 1 to a number and removing 1 from a number .. Last thing, show the request please

Comment: Read the updated comment please. And show the request

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question.

Comment: i will send request about animal price form url and insert them into dynamoDB

Comment: now i edit the question here's a request